# Actionscript 3.0 - Get variable from superclass to new object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How do I do this?

```
public class SuperClass extends MovieClip {
  public static var test:String = 'Hello world';
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  public function SubClass() {
    var unit = new Unit();
    addChild(Unit);
  }
}

public class Unit extends MovieClip {
  public function Unit() {
    //Get variable:test from SuperClass??
    trace(SubClass.test); //Error
  }
}
```

Hope you understand what I want to do?
Want to get the variable 'test' from the SuperClass in my new Unit added in SubClass.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case your class named `SubClass` uses the `Unit` class through composition, not inheritance. As such the `Unit` class knows nothing about `SubClass` or `SuperClass` or any of their properties like the `test` property.

You can, however, pass a value into the `Unit` class through it's constructor (or just set a value directly onto a property of the `Unit` class):

(showing the last two classes only)

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

  public function SubClass() {
    var unit = new Unit(test);
    addChild(Unit);
  }
}

public class Unit extends MovieClip {

  private var test:String;

  public function Unit(test:String) {
    this.test = test;
  }
}
```

**[Edit]**

Since your `Unit` class needs to access many properties of `SubClass` (and/or `SuperClass`), you might want to just pass an instance of `SubClass` to `Unit`:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

  public function SubClass() {
    var unit = new Unit(this);
    addChild(Unit);
  }
}

public class Unit extends MovieClip {

  private var subClass:SubClass;

  public function Unit(subClass:SubClass) {
    this.subClass = subClass;
    trace(subClass.text);
  }
}
```

How you actually solve this depends on your use case. But there is no fundamental shortcut to do what you are asking.

Comment: I already knew that method of passing the variable through the constructor. And it works fine. But just a pain in the a** to do this if i have alot of variables I want to pass through. But can it be done easier? :-)

Comment: well. Then I'll do it that way. Thanks!